# return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Umi Falafel'

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have exported csv files from the database and would like to store the csv information in my django models. I am receiving the ValueError problem.

I have tried converting the string to an integer within my .py files

**load_vendor_data.py**

```
import csv
from polls.models import Vendors

with open('../data/csv/Vendors.csv') as cap:
     reader = csv.reader(cap)
     # i = 0
     for row in reader:
       vendors = Vendors(row[0],row[1],row[2])
       vendors.save()
       # i = i + 1
```

**models.py**

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   price_range = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name


class Act(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Stage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Start_Time = models.TimeField()
   End_Time = models.TimeField()
   Date = models.DateField()

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\2019-ca472-John-Tawhid\festimaps\polls\load_vendor_data.py", line 9, in <module>
    vendors.save()
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 904, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 934, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1210, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1104, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 74, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\tawhi\project\cfehome\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Umi Falafel'
```

I expect no errors when importing the csv files inside the django db

Answer (score 1):

You should always use keyword arguments, not positional ones, when instantiating models.

```
vendors = Vendors(name=row[0], location=row[1], price_range=row[2])
```

Comment: Im still receiving an error:     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch